# Enabling multiple CPUs prevents Ubuntu 18.04 guest from booting in VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Using VirtualBox 4.3.18 r96516 on a Windows 8.1 host with `NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4`. There are two guest virtual machines.

1. Windows XP (32 bit) using 2 CPUs
2. Ubuntu (64 bit) [18.04] using 1 CPU

Both guest OSes boot fine. But when I change the Ubuntu guest to use 2 CPUs, the boot sequence shows the normal GNU GRUB screen, and thereafter a blank screen with a single underscore (_). The boot process never proceeds any further, even after waiting several minutes.

How to allow Ubuntu 18.04 guests to use 2 CPUs?

If I power off the VM, change settings back to 1 CPU, then Ubuntu 18.04 boots correctly.

Note: The `Processor` slider is not greyed out and **can** be changed (a problem referred to in similar questions).

I uninstalled VirtualBox 4.3.18 r96516 (completely removing all files in `%ProgramFiles`/Oracle/VirtualBox). Then installed VirtualBox 5.2.34 r133893 (with the Guest Additions extension). This has not helped. With 1 CPU, Ubuntu 18.04 boots successfully, but with 2 CPUs the guest OS never boots up.

Comment: How many cores/CPUs does your host machine have?

Comment: When I type `set` from the command-line, the number of processors is shown as 4. You get the same information from `Task Manager`. This is already in the question, first line.

Comment: Are you trying to run both VMs simultaneously? Does the same issue occur if you just launch the Ubuntu VM?

Comment: No, the VMs are not running simultaneously. Start XP with 2 CPUs, works. Stop. Start Ubuntu with 1 CPU, works. Stop. Start Ubuntu with 2 CPUs, fails. Kill. Start Ubuntu with 1 CPU, works.